# how to configure IIS 7 so partial content requets/range requests on mp4 static files work.

Tags: iis, iis-7, google-chrome

I need help on how to setup IIS 7 so it can handle partial requests/range requests for serving mp4 files so Chrome can position seek and loop video.

From what I have read IIS is supposed to support this out of the box, but my setup does not appear to be honoring this. I also read though that if it is hosting ASP.NET site it will not honor the range requests. I do not need ASP.NET features - but I do not see how to change this either in IIS.

Comment: They probably *do* work. I'd recommend testing by inserting a *Range:* header into the request either via a Telnet session or with `curl`'s `--header` parameter. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/http-status-code-206-commad-line-test/ for detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect this to Just Work given default behaviour, if such requests use the Static File Handler, as I think they do by default.

Use Failed Request Tracing with a rule targeting *.mp4, status code 200, to validate whether range requests are working or not.

If the eventual handler of the request is the StaticFileHandler, I'd expect it's working.

If your requests are being funneled through a .Net handler or module, then don't... exclude the handler.